# How can I share my current Chrome profile with Selenium?

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I'd like to use Selenium alongside my current Chrome profile, which may or may not be in use.  I'd like to be able to launch some Selenium automation that is aware of (for example) any currently set cookies from my current Chrome session.  I'd also like my Selenium automation to be able to change cookies that will still persist in my local profile.

Example:

1. I'd like to be able to manually log into a website (without
   Selenium)
2. I'd like to then launch some Selenium automation that
   assumes I'm already logged in (which I would be)
3. I'd like to then make some type of change through the Selenium automation
4. I'd like to close out the Selenium automation and see the changes that were made reflected in my original, manually-initiated, session

I know this can technically be achieved by setting user-data-dir in ChromeOptions, however that results in the following errors:

```
[20644:39092:1124/205239:ERROR:cache_util_win.cc(20)] Unable to move the cache: 0
[20644:39092:1124/205239:ERROR:cache_util.cc(134)] Unable to move cache folder C:\Users\****\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\ShaderCache\GPUCache to C:\Users\****\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\ShaderCache\old_GPUCache_000
[20644:39092:1124/205239:ERROR:cache_creator.cc(134)] Unable to create cache
[20644:39092:1124/205239:ERROR:shader_disk_cache.cc(585)] Shader Cache Creation failed: -2
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you reviewed the permissions of the directories listed in the error message?  They should share the same group and have write permissions.

This should solve the messages, but your implementation looks to be correct.

Comment: I have however I believe the issue is that they are in use but that is what I want. I want to have Selenium share the profile that I'm currently using.

Comment: In case you need to verify if in fact these files are open and in use, you can use the lsof command to query open file and check for files in use.  Sounds like you're on that track already though.